# In rails 4, how can I manipulate strong parameters before creation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, devise, acts-as-taggable-on, strong-parameters

I am trying to convert an array inputed from a form multiple select field into a string separating the elements with commas.  The gem i am using requires a tag_field in the form of a string separated by commas, but my multiple select field creates an array. Strong parameters reject the array so I need to convert the array to a string.  Here is the code I have now in my application controller, but it is not working.

```
def configure_devise_params
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) do |u|
        u[:tag_list].join(', ')
        u.permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation,
        :profile_name, :how_did_you_hear, :first_name, :last_name, :type, :tag_list)
    end
end
```

Before I was adding :tag_list, I had the following code that worked:

```
def configure_devise_params
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) do |u|
        u.permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation,
        :profile_name, :how_did_you_hear, :first_name, :last_name, :type)
    end
end
```

How do I fix this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a simple way to permit array.

Example:
 `params.require(:article).permit(:title, {:rubric_ids => []})`

In your case it would be smth like this:

```
def configure_devise_params
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) do |u|
    u.permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation,
    :profile_name, :how_did_you_hear, :first_name, :last_name, :type, {:tag_list => []})
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm not trying to get it to permit an array though.  The gem requires a string with comma separated elements, so I'm trying to convert the array to a string.

Comment: Can you specify gem name? You can try to join params after permit operation.

Comment: I'm using the acts-as-taggable-on gem.  What is join params?

Comment: Somewhere you smth like User.create(configure_devise_params). Am I right? If so there is a dirty code to do what you want 
def configure_devise_params
  result = devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) do |u|
    u.permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation,
    :profile_name, :how_did_you_hear, :first_name, :last_name, :type, {:tag_list => []})
  end
  result[:tag_list] = tag_list[:tag_list].join(', ')
  
  result
end

Comment: Sorry but I don't know how to do in another way. You can monkey patch gem in order to pass array, not string.

Comment: Awesome!  It worked!  Why does it work?  What exactly is it telling rails to do?

Comment: Firstly it permit tag list array. The result would be hash with indifferent access. Then I just change 1 value from array to sting.