# Allowing users to select tags on sign up form using acts-as-taggable-on

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, acts-as-taggable-on

Is there a way to allow the users to select from the predefined tags while signing up with devise?

registrations/new.html.erb

```
<h2>Sign up</h2>

<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %>
    <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password %>
    <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off" %></br >
    <% if @minimum_password_length %>
    <em>(<%= @minimum_password_length %> characters minimum)</em>
    <% end %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation %>
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off" %>
  </div>

</div>
 <% tag_cloud User.tag_counts_on(:tags).order("name ASC"), %w[s m l] do |tag, css_class| %>
    <label class="category-select">
      <%= check_box_tag 'tag[]', (tag.name), false, class: 'tag-color' %>
      <span class="tag-name"><%= tag.name %></span>
    </label>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Sign up" %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```

application_controller.rb

```
def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:email, :password, :tag_list, :tag, :context_list, :context) }
  end
```

user.rb

```
acts_as_taggable_on :tags, :context
```

This is what i got so far for my sign up page. What do i need to do so that when user fills in the email, password and checks necessary tags and clicks signup, the tags gets saved for that user? Would really appreciate your help guys. Thanks

Comment: Did you add the `before_action` filter in your application_controller? If yes, what is the error message? https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#strong-parameters

Comment: I did, there's no error message it just doesn't save the tag i checked.

Answer (score 0):

tag_list must be an array. As the [doc](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#strong-parameters) says:

> An array is not one of Strong Parameters' permitted scalars, so we
>   need to configure Devise.

In your case it would be something like this:

```
def configure_devise_params
   devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) do |u|
     u.permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, {:context_list => []}, {:tag_list => []})
   end
end
```

I don't think you need `tag` as well as `tag_list`. act-as-taggable only sends tag_list. You migth find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19880138/in-rails-4-how-can-i-manipulate-strong-parameters-before-creation) question useful.

update:

```
 def configure_devise_params
   result = devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) do |u|
     u.permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, {:tag_list => []})         
   end
   result[:tag_list] = result[:tag_list].join(', ')
   result
 end
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply however, the user tag_list is still empty. Do I need a create action in the devise controller?

Comment: i tried it. i get `undefined local variable or method 'tag_list' for #<Devise::SessionsController:0x007ffab7de9590>` . Is it because devise doesn't know about the tagging?

Comment: sorry, There was typo. Second last line should be `result[:tag_list] = result[:tag_list].join(', ')`

Comment: Sorry but any idea why i get `undefined method 'permit' for :tag_list:Symbol` now

Comment: Looks like `result[:tag_list] = result[:tag_list].join(', ')` is causing this error

Comment: you should read this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19880138/in-rails-4-how-can-i-manipulate-strong-parameters-before-creation

Comment: specially the comments

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92051/discussion-between-ray-and-sonalkr132).